# Why does xpath find excluded nodes again?

Tags: r, xpath, rvest, xml2

Consider this page:

```
<n1 class="a">
  1
</n1>
<n1 class="b">
  <b>bold</b>
  2
</n1>
```

If I first select the first `n1` using `class="a"`, I should be excluding the second `n1`, and indeed this appears true:

```
library(rvest)
b_nodes = read_html('<n1 class="a">1</n1>
<n1 class="b"><b>bold</b>2</n1>') %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//n1[@class="b"]')
b_nodes
# {xml_nodeset (1)}
# [1] <n1 class="b"><b>bold</b>2</n1>
```

However if we now use this "subsetted" page:

```
b_nodes %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//n1')
# {xml_nodeset (2)}
# [1] <n1 class="a">1</n1>
# [2] <n1 class="b"><b>bold</b>2</n1>
```

How did the `1` node get "re-discovered"??

Note: I know how to get what I want with two separate xpaths. This is a conceptual question about why the "subsetting" didn't work as expected. My understanding was that `b_nodes` should have excluded the first node altogether -- the `b_nodes` object shouldn't even know that node exists.

Comment: A simpler illustration: `b_nodes %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//n1')`. Looks like it's not designed to be chained / consistently points at the original object.

Comment: @Frank good point, I thought I'd tried that and it didn't work. I'll edit it in

Answer (score 2):

```
html_nodes(xpath = '//n1')
```

`//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::n1`, the current node is **the whole document**

change it to `.//n1`, `.` means the current node is **what you selected before**

Comment: @MichaelChirico when you use `//` you are query the whole document, no matter what sub-node you are.

Comment: I still find it strange that the other nodes weren't deleted by the first expression. i.e., the "whole document", to me, should only be `<n1 class="b">...</n1>`, which is what displays from `b_nodes`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not shure what are you trying to do, but, Why do not you try to traverse the nodes with a foreach? I mean:

```
$XML = read_html('
<n1s>
<n1 class="a">1</n1>
<n1 class="b"><b>bold</b>2</n1></n1s>') %>%


$valueA = '';
$valueB = '';    
foreach ($XML->xpath('//n1') as $n1) {
        switch ((string)$n1['class']){
              case 'a':
                    $valueA = $XML->n1;
                     break;
              case 'b':
                    $valueB = $XML->n1;
                     break;
        }
    }
```

I hope this can help you.
Regards!

Comment: See edit, this isn't a question of how to do something