# Try to fill with " " in case of error in loop of html_nodes

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping, html-parsing, rvest

I'm trying to extract data by text mining with `html_nodes` using urls that I have saved into an object called `url`. I have created a loop which reads and scrapes each url.

```
library(rvest)
for (i in url) {
  tex <- read_html(i)
  p_text <- tex %>%
    html_nodes("p") %>%
    html_text()
  a <- p_text
}
```

Because some url isn't working, the following message appears:

> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Could not resolve host: app.lo

I want to introduce in the loop the following: if the url doesn't work, assume the text blank, and let the loop continue. This is a really a problem because the loop is stopping and I was trying to eliminate some urls, but I have around 200,000 htmls.

Comment: If you use `lapply` (or `purrr::map` variants) with `tryCatch`/`purrr::possibly`/`purrr::safely`, the results will automatically be stored in a list you can clean up afterwards. That said, 200k URLs is a lot! If you use `Sys.sleep` to wait 10 seconds between calls (a common request in robots.txt so hosts don't inadvertently get DDOSed by scapers), it would take 23 days even if the code itself was instantaneous. Thus, start by looking for a more direct approach to get your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by a simple `tryCatch` and error handling. I also introduced a list `a` in which you can store your outputs (currently you will be overwriting your output in each loop.)

```
library(rvest)
a <- list()
for (i in 1:length(url)) {
  url_use = url[[i]]
  a[[i]] <- 
    tryCatch({
        read_html(url_use) %>%
            html_nodes("p") %>%
            html_text()
    }, error = function(e) NA)
}
```

Let me know if this is not what you had in mind.

Comment: will that assignment ` a[[i]] <-  ` work from inside the `error` function?

Comment: @R.S. Uhh, nooo... (groans at one's own stupidity). Updated answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just switch to `html_node` instead of `html_nodes`.

`html_node` will return `NA` if nothing is matched.

Without any sample URLs, I can't test, however.

See these Q&A for more reference

- [Equivalent of which in scraping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708685/equivalent-of-which-in-scraping)
- [Different number of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619312/different-number-of-nodes/47619741#47619741)
- [Reading in html with R rvest. How do I check if a CSS selector class contains anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597294/reading-in-html-with-r-rvest-how-do-i-check-if-a-css-selector-class-contains-an/46599311#46599311)
- [Scraping a table from a section in Wikipedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538366/scraping-a-table-from-a-section-in-wikipedia)
- [Why does xpath find excluded nodes again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167159/why-does-xpath-find-excluded-nodes-again)

Comment: I think this would be simplest way of solving this problem. Thank you for this!